# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'io.realm.RealmSwit' is correct

Tags: realm

[image]

When I try to archive from Xcode, I get the following error:

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle
>   identifier 'io.realm.RealmSwit' is correct.

My Bundle Indentifiter is the same for both the ItunesConnecti site and the App Store Connect site.

My app uses Realm, RealmSwift Framework.

But why do not you use the bundle identifier
I do not know if you ask `io.realm.RealmSwit`.

If you know the related details, please let me explain in detail.

Comment: Do you have a valid Provisioning Profile for this Bundle ID? If so, are you correctly logged in into Xcode with the Apple Developer account associated with this Bundle ID?

Comment: yes. I download Provisioning Profile. and bundle ID  is exactly